# TikZ in LyX: Package tikz error?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx

I am trying to compile a document that uses the tikzpicture and pgf packages, but I am getting this error

[image]

**UPDATE**

Code:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
         width=0.75\columnwidth,
         xtick={10,20,...,40},
         xlabel=Tamaño del arreglo (miles),
         ylabel=Tiempo (ms),
         legend pos=outer north east,
         title=\textbf{Comparación}]
    \addplot coordinates{(10,100) (20,300) (30,400) (40,600)};
    \addplot coordinates{(10,400) (20,600) (30,200) (40,400)};
    \addplot coordinates{(10,600) (20,500) (30,100) (40,200)};
    \addplot coordinates{(10,600) (20,100) (30,500) (40,100)};
    \addplot coordinates{(10,300) (20,100) (30,200) (40,500)};
    \addplot coordinates{(10,600) (20,200) (30,400) (40,500)};
    \legend{Selección,Inserción,Mezcla,Montículos,Rápido,Residuos}
    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Latex preamble:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\date{}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is quite descriptive; you are using some code that requires the `calc` library, so need to load it; add

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
```

after

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Try processing this sample document exactly as it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
         width=0.75\columnwidth,
         xtick={10,20,...,40},
         xlabel=Tamaño del arreglo (miles),
         ylabel=Tiempo (ms),
         legend pos=outer north east,
         title=\textbf{Comparación}]
    \addplot coordinates{(10,100) (20,300) (30,400) (40,600)};
    \addplot coordinates{(10,400) (20,600) (30,200) (40,400)};
    \addplot coordinates{(10,600) (20,500) (30,100) (40,200)};
    \addplot coordinates{(10,600) (20,100) (30,500) (40,100)};
    \addplot coordinates{(10,300) (20,100) (30,200) (40,500)};
    \addplot coordinates{(10,600) (20,200) (30,400) (40,500)};
    \legend{Selección,Inserción,Mezcla,Montículos,Rápido,Residuos}
    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

From the comments (and a discussion in chat) it was clear that the problem was an outdated LaTeX system.

Comment: Thanks that fixed one thing, however I keep getting: -Package pgfkeys Error and Missing \begin{document}

Comment: What's the complete error message you are getting? Can we see the complete TikZ code producing the error?

Comment: \usepgfplotslibrary
                        {groupplots}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: Updated screenshot: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/jFpfW.png)

Comment: The last line refers to `legend pos` which suggests that you are using the `pgfplots` package. Did you load this package?

Comment: Yes; I have updated the question with the full Latex preamble.

Comment: @metroxylon I've updated my answer with a test code; please run it exactly as it is (it works OK in my system) and report the outcome.

Comment: Outcome (using pdflatex in Terminal): "[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/legend pos' and I am goin
g to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21     \end{semilogyaxis}"

Comment: @metroxylon all seems to indicate that you are using an outdated LaTeX system. Do you know the version of your LaTeX distribution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4726/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-metroxylon)